# What are those little "u" in my tuple? (python 2.7)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

So i'm getting data from something sqlExtractor, I can't touch to sqlExtractor.
problem is sqlExtractor is giving me a list of tuple (I'd like a list of list)

So I thought about that :

```
myNewList = []
for tuple in myList:
    myNewList.append(list(tuple))
```

problem is, my data are filled with little "u", what do they mean?
They don't really bother me but since myNewList[i][j] will return the value without the "u".
But I'd like to understand.

So, what are they?

Thanks.

example - a tuple before and after conversion :

```
(u'Pado', u'Seba*', u'B31', u'27/02/2011', u'SINA', u'2', u'5', u'Paris', u'Zone bleu', u'211')
[u'Pado', u'Seba*', u'B31', u'27/02/2011', u'SINA', u'2', u'5', u'Paris', u'Zone bleu', u'211']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `u` indicates that the string is a unicode object. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for details

Answer (score 4):

These are Unicode strings. See the [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).